# Variable "captcha_code" does not exist Gregwar

Tags: forms, symfony, bundle, captcha, php-5.3

everybody i'm trying to add a captcha to my form with Gregwar/CaptchaBundle but i face a probleme :

Variable "captcha_code" does not exist  when i pay this part of my code  :

========================================================================

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
 {% block captcha_widget %}
 {% spaceless %}
<img src="{{ captcha_code }}" title="captcha" width="{{ captcha_width }}" height="{{ captcha_height }}" />
 {{ form_row(form.captcha) }}
  {% endspaceless %}
 {% endblock %}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable `form` inside of widget block already contains the captcha field (not the whole form), so the correct way is to use `form_widget(form)` instead of `form_row(form.captcha)` :

```
{% block captcha_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    <img src="{{ captcha_code }}" title="captcha" width="{{ captcha_width }}" height="{{ captcha_height }}" />
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you but i figured out it by myselfe the best way to solve my problem was to

configure captcha field in my form builder

```
$builder->add('captcha', 'Gregwar\CaptchaBundle\Type\CaptchaType',array(
            'width' => 200,
            'height' => 50,
            'length' => 6,
            'quality' => 90,
            'distortion' => true,
            'background_color' => [115, 194, 251],
            'max_front_lines' => 0,
            'max_behind_lines' => 0,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control',
            'rows'=> "6"
            )
        ));
```

and  in my twig template only call this small part of code :

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
{% block captcha_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
       {{ form_row(form.captcha) }}
{% endspaceless %}

{% endblock %}
</div>
```